# Display pop up on first visit to site using cookies

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cookies

I am using the code in the jsfiddle to generate a pop up when the user visits my site for the first time.

I want to modify the alert and turn it in to a Bootstrap modal rather than a boring pop up.

This is the existing alert

```
 alert("Your Message Goes here and you only get to see it once!");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TWB68/1/

How can I modify this alert to be a modal / div that does the same thing

Comment: replace the alert with the modal code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will be your `modal` Code

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/TWB68/131/)**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Welcome Message</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Your Message Goes here and you only get to see it once!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of `alert` add this below

```
$("#myModal").modal("show");
```

Comment: Anytime!! Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `div` inside the modal content then assign it by using `.html` on the div e.g.:

```
...
if (visit == null) {
        //alert("Your Message Goes here and you only get to see it once!");
        $('#div_inside_modal').html('Your Message Goes here and you only get to see it once!');
        var expire = new Date();
        expire = new Date(expire.getTime() + 7776000000);
        document.cookie = "cookie=here; expires=" + expire;
    }
...
```

Well, of course you need to show modal on page load.